# SQL Server - changing definition of column that appears in multi tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

many of tables in my DB have a Boolean column 'IsDeleted'.

I need to alter the column in all tables, that the default value will be zero, and then update all old records with value null, to be with value zero.

There is a way to do it beside writing a script for every table?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to do a script for this I'm afraid. Or manually modify each field. Why not write a script? Wouldn't be that difficult to do.

Comment: A dynamic SQL approach would work, although you'll need to create a new column, update the value in said column, delete the old one, then rename the new one

Comment: SQLAndOtherStuffGuy, there are more then100 tables with that column, so a script for every one is too much work.

Comment: JohnHC , i can't delete the old one, because then the data will be deleted.

Comment: @Zag Gol I think with JohnHC is saying is that you would create a new column. Update the data in that column with what's in the existing column. Delete the old column and then rename the new one. The problem is that you cannot add a default constraint of true|false to a bit column and also allow NULLs.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a good starting point to generate the CReate, Update and Rename scripts required. Advisory: TEST ON BACKUP OF DATABASE FIRST.

```
     select  
'ALTER TABLE dbo.' + O.Name + ' ADD IsDeletedNew bit default 0;
 UPDATE dbo.' + O.Name + ' SET IsDeletedNew = 1 WHERE IsDeleted = 1;
 UPDATE dbo.' + O.Name + ' SET IsDeletedNew = 0 WHERE IsDeleted = 0 OR IsDeleted IS NULL;
 ALTER TABLE dbo.' + O.Name + ' DROP COLUMN IsDeleted;
 EXECUTE sp_rename N''dbo.' +  O.Name + '.IsDeletedNew'', N''Tmp_IsDeleted_1'', ''COLUMN''
 EXECUTE sp_rename N''dbo.' +  O.Name + '.Tmp_IsDeleted_1'', N''IsDeleted'', ''COLUMN'' '

from syscolumns C
Inner join sysobjects o on C.ID = O.ID
where c.name = 'IsDeleted'
```

Answer (score 0):

With so many tables, do the `alter` using dynamic SQL

```
declare @tab_name varchar(120)
declare @the_sql varchar(1000)

declare MyCursor cursor
for
select distinct table_name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where column_name = 'IsNumeric'

open MyCursor
fetch next from MyCursor into @tab_name
while @@fetchstatus = 0
begin
  set @the_sql = 'alter table ' + @tab_name + ' add NewNumeric bit default 0'
  execute (@the_sql)
  fetch next from MyCursor into @tab_name
end
close MyCursor
deallocate MyCursor
```

rinse and repeat to updatethe values, delete the old column and then update the new column

Comment: @TT. My bad, threw it together asa  pointer, rather than an actual take and use proc...

Answer (score 0):

First, I can set a default value for a boolean filed. It worked for me.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].<TableName> ADD DEFAULT 0 FOR IsDeleted
```

This is my script that sets default value for every 'IsDeleted' field that doesn't have a defualt value. It worked for me.

```
DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(300)

DECLARE CUR CURSOR 
FOR
SELECT t.name AS 'TableName'
FROM        sys.columns c
JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name = 'IsDeleted' 
    AND (SELECT object_definition(default_object_id) AS definition
        FROM   sys.columns
        WHERE  name      ='IsDeleted'
            AND    object_id = object_id(t.name)) is  null

OPEN CUR

FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @NAME

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
      SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE [dbo].'+@NAME+' ADD DEFAULT 0 FOR IsDeleted'
      --PRINT @SQL  -- will print all the update scripts
      EXEC Sp_executesql @SQL

      FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @NAME
  END

CLOSE CUR

DEALLOCATE CUR
```